# Mixing color in css with overlayed division

Tags: html, css

I have a div in html with class box and i have used pseudo classes :after for blue border around box and :before for overlay orange color box as in image. I want exact same result as in image . I got the box i got the icon, i got the text everything as in image , all i dont get is the silver color effect in text and icon.

**Expected Result**

[image: Expected result]

**Obtained Result**

[image: Result Obtained]

**HTML**

```
enter code here
<section class="section why-us">
     <div class="container">
        <div class="box left bordered-box selected">
            <img src="images/why-us-icon8.png" class="section-img">
            <h2>Online Research</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.why-us .box{
            background:#F1F1F1;
            margin-bottom:30px;
            height:250px;
        }
        .bordered-box h2{
            color:#2c3e50;
        }
        .bordered-box:before{
            content:'';
            position:absolute;
            top:10px;
            left:10px;
            width:90%;
            height:90%;
            border:2px solid #B2E9F1;
            z-index:1;
        }
        .selected:after{
            content:'';
            position:absolute;
            top:107px;
            width:260px;
            height:142px;
            background:#E67E22;
            background:rgba(255,140,0,0.4);
            opacity:0.9;
        }
```

Comment: Please provide your code,

Comment: `::after` is **not** a pseudo-class...it's a **pseudo-element**

Comment: my bad! anyway i do think you got what i meant

Comment: ... **minimal** code in a working demo would be ideal. We only need 1 div...not 7 or 8

Answer (score 0):

You could change those elements with css on :hover of the container, but I'm not too sure you can change the colours by means of a position: absolute; orange colour container transitioning over these elements...

As already requested, your code would be great.